# Show liferay input editor

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, liferay, liferay-ide

I'm trying to create a liferay portlet with a input editor. For achieve this I'm using:

- Liferay 6.2 GA5 bundled with Tomcat 7
- Liferay Plugins SDK 6.2 GA5
- Liferay IDE in Eclipse, 3.0.0 GA1

And I tried to create a portlet with the following content:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.UnicodeFormatter" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<aui:button-row cssClass="guestbook-buttons">
    <aui:button value="TESTING"></aui:button>
</aui:button-row>

<liferay-ui:input-editor initMethod="initEditor" name="mieditor">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function <portlet:namespace />initEditor() { 
        return "<%= UnicodeFormatter.toString("working") %>";
    }
</script>
</liferay-ui:input-editor>

Editor up.
```

The code indicated before creates a portlet with a button and input editor, but it does not show the editor, only the button and the sentence `Editor up`. You can see a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Do you know why the portlet does not show the input editor?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to include the Liferay-ui taglib.Just add this to your jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
```

For future references,if you are developing in an IDE,it will show you a warning of Unknown tag,and hence it fails to resolve the tag or it's special usage.

Comment: It was that, Thank you a lot! The matter is that I was getting no warning of unknown tag, that's why I did not get the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use alloy CkEditor or FCKeditor.
Alloy CKEditor [Click here](http://alloyeditor.com/guides/)

FCKEditor [click here](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1692669)

Comment: I tried to use FCKEditor, but I get the following error: `The absolut uri: http://java.fckeditor.net cannot be resolved in web.xml or jar files deployed with this application`

Answer (score 0):

Liferay implements CKEditor inside its own liferay-ui taglib.

If you want to use it dinamically I recommend you tinymce editor that you can customize automatically in its own page with your needs.